# Phonegap audio element

Tags: cordova, html5-audio

I'm trying to play music in Phonegap using an audio tag.  Unfortunately, if I change the "src" attribute dynamically, eventually it gets messed up and stuck.  On Android the play head jumps to the end instantly and refuses to play anything, and on iOS it plays the music anyway but turns the controls into the words "Cannot play this file" so you can't control it anymore.  This does not happen when I use it in a regular web browser.  Is there any quick fix for this, like re-creating the audio element every time you play something?

I noticed Phonegap has an audio API.  Perhaps this is more reliable than using audio elements in phonegap?  Is there any simple audio element replacement for use in phonegap?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After a pretty frustrating experience with the Phonegap Audio API, I've decided that using Phonegap to play music is not practical.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with Audio approach if phonegap is there is no guaranty it is supported (for instance android's before 2.3 have problom in supporting it) and you can never know what would happen in different platforms , i suggest you to use phonegap media API because it's a native approach(it has different ways in various platforms) so your audio will play in best shape .

quick example :

```
   // Audio player
    //
    var my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

    // Update media position every second
    var mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
        // get media position
        my_media.getCurrentPosition(
            // success callback
            function(position) {
                if (position > -1) {
                    console.log((position) + " sec");
                }
            },
            // error callback
            function(e) {
                console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
            }
        );
    }, 1000);
```

find more information at : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_media.md.html